# How can i cycle between different game status messages in JDA?

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I am trying to make the bot show it's server count, which gets updated every 20 seconds of so!

I have tried to put it in a loop after an await ready event:

```
public void onReady(ReadyEvent event) {

while (true) {

TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(20)
event.JDA().getPresence().setGame(Game.watching(event.getJDA().getGuilds().size() + "servers"));
}
}
```

This has succeeded in displaying the amount of servers it joined but this stopped any other code from being run.

So how can I do this without the rest of the program being ignored?

Comment: Use a `ScheduledExecutorService` and schedule at fixed rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try setting an interval and doing the update on it

```java
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
Runnable task = () -> {
event.JDA().getPresence().setGame(Game.watching(event.getJDA().getGuilds().size() + "servers"));
};

executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, 0, 20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

or using Timer

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

@Override
public void run() {   
event.JDA().getPresence().setGame(Game.watching(event.getJDA().getGuilds().size() + "servers"));
}
}, 0, 20000 );
```

setting it inside a `while(true)` makes it stop there, because it extecutes on the main thread whitout creating a new one.

Comment: This is java not javascript.

Comment: sorry, didn't realize there is a Discord-JDA, I only knew about js and python